# Uncaught Error during socket run on browser ( Uncaught ReferenceError : io is not defined )

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Recently I started to learn Nodejs. and presently working on a chat server. 
I know this question asked many times. I also have seen all solution but they can't solve my problem. when I run this HTML code in the browser then it 
shows  **Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined** . any idea behind this error. I asked this question after spend 4 hours on this and not getting the solution.

```
<!--  CODE RUN on my browser -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CharRoom</title>

<!-- below js file working correctly when I click on this then it open 
  socket.io.js file -->

<link src="/socket.io/socket.io.js">
<link 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
<script> 
 var socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to chat Room</h1>
</body></html>



// code on my server
app = require('express')();
var server = http.Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Esta");
});
server.listen(8000,function (req,res) {
console.log("Chat is running on port "+ 8000);  
});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`?

Comment: Thanks Bro, it's a minor mistake but i didn't catch it, Thanks again for reply

Comment: No problem, did it fix your issue?

Comment: yes my issue is fixed

Comment: Great, I added my response as a real answer so you can mark it as done so it doesn't stay open as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are loading a js script, replace

```
<link src="/socket.io/socket.io.js">
```

with

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```